# How to add a hue of one categorical column to Seaborn barplot (of each column mean and std)?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

`sns.barplot(data = df, ci='sd')`  gives a barplot of each column mean with std like below.

[image: barplot]

Let's say there is one column named 'category', which has 3 kinds of values A, B, and C.

I want to add a hue parameter to the barplot from this column in order to split each bar of column mean into three according to the category. Like this:

[image: expected]

If I directly add `hue = 'category'`, I got an error `` Cannot use `hue` without `x` and `y` `` .

What should x and y be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, it looks like if you don't pass `x` or `y`, then your DataFrame will be interpreted as 'wide-form', and each numeric column will be plotted. Then if you want to maintain the plot layout you have, but use `hue='category'`, you'll need to convert your DataFrame to 'long-form' using `melt`, using the former columns -- now the `var_name` column -- as `x`. Without the specifics, I can't say exactly which columns you'll need to use, but it should look roughly like this:

```
melted_df = df.melt(var_name='variable', value_name='value')
sns.barplot(melted_df, x='variable', y='value', hue='category')
```

Does this work for you?

Note that in general, Seaborn expects your data in long format. I think you'll find it makes most operations more convenient, as each "unit" of the plot is expressed as a group in a groupby, which is simpler than dealing with grouping along both the row and column axes.

Comment: Thanks, your method is enlightening. I made a little modification like `df.melt( id_vars='category', var_name='variable', value_name='value')` then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with separate subplots for each column, one way of doing this would be like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(df.columns), figsize=(120,6))
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    sns.barplot(x='category', y=df.columns[i], ax=ax[i], data=df, ci='sd')
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, there's one error  `Neither the \`x\` nor \`y\` variable appears to be numeric`, but I can still get a figure.

Comment: Ok, I assumed numeric columns for y axis. Glad to see BallpointBen's recommendation worked for you!